# phpinfo() and convert --version show different versions of ImageMagick

Tags: centos, php, centos-7, imagemagick, php-extensions

I'm running CentOS 7.7 and a few days ago I noticed that my ImageMagick library is missing the ImagickKernel class. So after a lot of research, I got to the conclusion that I'm running an outdated ImageMagick library 6.7.8-9 even though everything was showing me signs that it's the latest...
I managed to install the latest from the source though, and now when I try 'convert --version', it shows me 7.0.10-2 which looks nice, however phpinfo is still showing me the old version 6.7.8-9...

I'm guessing that it's because the php extension was compiled with the old version, but I couldn't find any help on this

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it. Seems like I just needed to restart the server :)